# Assistance with setting up Classes and Objects in C#

Tags: c#, class, oop, object

Definitely still a Programmer in Training but trying to make something for my project and going around in circles.  Kindly asking for any guidance in setting up my classes.  I'm developing the code for other's to consume via a .dll Assembly.

Let me just describe a simple class (using a Base class) called Car with a few properties.  These then are the requirements for what I am trying to achieve:

1) The ability to create instances of the class Car.  All properties of user instantiated Car objects should be changeable.

2) The ability to offer them 3 pre-generated Car objects for them to use right out of the box.  How about: Honda CRV, Toyota Prius, Nissan Rogue

3) The pre-generated Cars (Honda CRV, Toyota Prius, Nissan Rogue) should be locked (read only?).  Even the properties in the Base class Transportation should be read only.

What is the best way to make this happen?  Do I use Static properties?  Do I use the readonly modifier?  Do I create a new Class called HondaCRV (for example) and use Car as a base class?  Then make things readonly in there?  What do I make public and private (or protected)?  Or do I just make a new Class called 'Cars' which expose my 3 pre-generated Cars (as properties) and nothing else?

I just don't know what is the best approach and one that that will give the best experience for the consumer of my Assembly.  I tried a few things and I got close, but I could never get the "Read-Only" to propagate down to the Base Class.

Please excuse any bad practices I may have written in my example code.  I am still a C# programmer in training.

Thank you in advance for any assistance you can offer me and trying to understand my post.  I'm happy (and excited) to learn and incorporate any ideas you may have for me.  And I am more than happy to clarify anything also.  I tried my best to express my requirements.

Amar

```
enum Terrain
{
    Land,
    Water,
    Air
}

class Transportation
{
    private Terrain terrainType;

    public Terrain TerrainType
    {
        get { return terrainType; }
        set { terrainType = value; }
    }
}

class Car:Transportation
{
    private string mfg;
    private string model;

    public string Mfg
    {
        get { return mfg; }
        set { mfg = value; }
    }

    public string Model
    {
        get { return model; }
        set { model = value; }
    }

    public Car(string Manufacturer, string CarModel)
    {
        Mfg = Manufacturer;
        Model = CarModel;
        TerrainType = Terrain.Land;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe one nice thing would be to have a static Cars class with three Properties...so when the user of my Assembly types in Cars.  then the three Pregenerated would appear only (HondaCRV, ToyotaPrius, NissanRogue).  I was able to do this but alas when I used the class I was able to change all the properties which I did not want.

Comment: Hi Amar, thank you for your question. Please consider posting it on [codereview.stackexchange.com/](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead since it is a much better fit there and you are more likely to get the kind of answers your expect.

Comment: One way of doing this would be to make every car read-only.  Modifying a car would mean creating a new car with the desired properties.

Comment: I agree, it sounds like making your classes immutable with parametrized constructors would solve the problem. Then, you can just define a pool of pre-created static cars.

Comment: If nothing else, the Make and Model of a car should *not* be mutable.  If those properties change, no one would consider it the same car as before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I'd do.  In real life, I'd probably have a `Manufacturer` table and a `Model` table in a database with a foreign key relationship between them.  Here, I'm modeling that with an `enum` and a `Dictionary`

I use the enum for the manufacturers.  This is a list that doesn't change very often (in the last decade or so, I can think of Genesis and Tesla as new manufacturers):

```
public enum CarManufacturer
{
    Acura,
    BMW,
    Buick,
    //fill in more
    Honda,
    Nissan,
    Tesla,
    Toyota,
    //etc
}
```

I left your 'Terrain` enum alone:

```
public enum Terrain
{
    Land,
    Water,
    Air
}
```

I changed your `Transportation` class to make it `abstract` (i.e., uninstantiable) and made the `TerrainType` property read only.  It can only be set in the constructor.  I also provide only a non-default constructor (so that that property must be set):

```
//This is abstract, no one can instantiate one, 
//only subclasses of this type can be constructed
public abstract class Transportation
{
    //this is read-only and must be set at construction time
    public Terrain TerrainType { get; }

    protected Transportation(Terrain terrainType)
    {
        TerrainType = terrainType;
    }

    //you probably want some methods (example, Move).  You can declare them "abstract"
}
```

Lots of changes to the car class:

- I make a private (static) dictionary of Manufacture <-> Model relationships.
- I provide limited access to that dictionary (clients can get a list of models and can validate if a specific model is made by a manufacturer)
- I made the Manufacturer and Model properties read-only - they both must be set at construction time
- I made the (only) constructor set those properties and call the non-default `Transportation` constructor as appropriate

The result looks like this:

```
public class Car : Transportation
{
    //in real life, this might be stored in a database
    private static readonly Dictionary<CarManufacturer, List<string>> CarModels =
        new Dictionary<CarManufacturer, List<string>>
        {
            {CarManufacturer.Acura, new List<string> {"RDX", "NSX", "MDX",}},
            {CarManufacturer.BMW, new List<string> {"2Series", "3Series", "etc",}},
            {CarManufacturer.Honda, new List<string> {"Civic", "Fit", "CRV", "Pilot",}},
            {CarManufacturer.Nissan, new List<string> {"Altima", "Maxima", "Rogue",}},
            {CarManufacturer.Toyota, new List<string> {"Corolla", "Prius",}},
        };

    //these get set at constructor time, they cannot be changed after that
    public CarManufacturer Manufacturer { get; }
    public string Model { get; }

    //you need to call the parameterized base class constructor
    public Car(CarManufacturer manufacturer, string model) : base(Terrain.Land)
    {
        Manufacturer = manufacturer;
        if (!ValidateCarModel(manufacturer, model))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Manufacturer {manufacturer} does not make model: {model}");
        }
        Model = model;
    }

    public static bool ValidateCarModel(CarManufacturer manufacturer, string model)
    {
        if (!CarModels.TryGetValue(manufacturer, out var models))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return models.Contains(model);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> ModelsForManufacturer(CarManufacturer manufacturer)
    {
        if (!CarModels.TryGetValue(manufacturer, out var models))
        {
            //maybe this should through, but this also makes sense
            return new List<string>();
        }
        //otherwise
        return models;
    }
}
```

Now I can create some cars.  I can test whether they are valid before I create them (or not):

```
 Car CRV, Rogue, Prius;
 if (Car.ValidateCarModel(CarManufacturer.Honda, "CRV"))
 {
     CRV = new Car(CarManufacturer.Honda, "CRV");
 }
 if (Car.ValidateCarModel(CarManufacturer.Nissan, "Rogue"))
 {
     Rogue = new Car(CarManufacturer.Nissan, "Rogue");
 }
 //I know that Toyota makes a Prius, so I just create one.  If I mess up, I'll get an exception
 Prius = new Car(CarManufacturer.Toyota, "Prius");
```

I think this meets your needs, and it's a little instructive

Notice that, other than that manufacturer enum, I could have roughly the same interface if I had done this with a database instead of the enum/Dictionary approach.

Comment: Oh my goodness FlyDog57, I would have never expected such a response to my post.  Thank you so much.  I'm in the processing of studying everyone's answer and learning the techniques and also researching the keywords in C# I am not familiar with.  This is so good.  I will post again soon as soon I digest everything.  The implementation looks like it should work.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to also just say Thank you for your answer Flydog57.

Comment: @AmarKapadia: One thing about the way this works is that if you are using a graphical UI, you can get the manufacturer names from the `CarManufacturer` type and use them to populate a listbox.  Then, once the user picks a manufacturer, you can get the list of models and populate a second list box.  Once the user picks from the two lists, then you know that the Manufacturer/Model combination is correct so you can instantiate a car.

Comment: Got it.  Haven't dived in the UI yet but I got your point (drawing from my MS Access Form Builder experience)  Yes, that would definitely enforce valid combinations.  So this is great.  I followed everything (put in Visual Studio also to really see how it all worked).  And it worked.  I was especially fascinated when I was testing...I accidentally did a Honda CRv and it flagged an exception.  There is so much to learn from your code but I believe your technique along with Dmitri's above is exactly what I needed.  My sincere thanks.  I'm so happy today.

Comment: You could code it to do a case independent comparison, and then fix the casing (look at `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` (or something like that, it could be "StringComparison" - I mix them up)).

Answer (score 1):

> Offer them 3 pre-generated Car objects for them to use right out of the box

How about just adding few instances of your class?

```
class Car
{
    ...

    public static readonly List<Car> Instances = new List<Car>() 
    {
        new Car() {Model = "Honda", Name = "CRV"}, 
        new Car() {Model = "Toyota", Name = "Prius"}, 
        new Car() {Model = "Nissan", Name = "Rogue"}
    };
}
```

They would be able to access them like this:

```
Car car = Car.Instances[0];
```

Comment: Thank you so much Hirasawa...this is a great answer but my only concern with this method is that users of the assembly would not know that Index 0 would be the Honda and index 1 would be the Prius, etc.  Otherwise, it totally makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know direct way to do what you want inside one class, but you can use combination of patterns as workaround: Immutable and Factory.

First, you declare ImmutableCar class, which hides base class setters like this.

```
public class ImmutableCar : Car
{
    public string Mfg
    {
        get { return base.Mfg; }
    }

    public string Model
    {
        get { return base.Model; }
    }

    public Terrain TerrainType
    {
        get { return base.TerrainType; }
    }

    internal ImmutableCar(string Manufacturer, string CarModel) : base (Manufacturer, CarModel)
    {
    }
}
```

Second, you make internal all constructors of Car and ImmutableCar classes, so user of you assembly cannot call it.

```
internal Car(string Manufacturer, string CarModel)
{
    Mfg = Manufacturer;
    Model = CarModel;
    TerrainType = Terrain.Land;
}

internal ImmutableCar(string Manufacturer, string CarModel) : base (Manufacturer, CarModel)
{
}
```

Third, you create Factory class, which instantiates all Cars. It offers your "read-only" cars via properties returns ImmutableCar. For editable cars it offers method GenerateCar.

```
public static class CarFactory
{
    public static ImmutableCar HondaCrv { 
        get
        {
            return new ImmutableCar("Honda", "Crv");
        }
    }

    public static Car GenerateCar(string Manufacturer, string CarModel)
    {
        return new Car(Manufacturer, CarModel);
    }
}
```

At last some testing.

```
        var landroverDiscovery = CarFactory.GenerateCar("Land Rover", "Discovery 2");
        landroverDiscovery.Model = "test"; // Ok
        var hondaCrv = CarFactory.HondaCrv;
        hondaCrv.Model = "test"; // Produces error
```

Comment: Dear Dmitry....thank you so much for the post.  I've reviewing everyone's post and studying the C# keywords I am not familiar with.  I will post again soon.  For now, just wanted to say my sincere thanks for offering me the implementation and code.

Comment: Dmitry!!!  Yes, everything works.  I had to paste and do some small adjustments just to get the code to work...but indeed it works exactly like I wanted.  This is so great.  I really have to study everything in detail and apply back to my project but you have shown me a path to exactly what I needed.  Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Glad to help you) one more thing you may want to know. There is "new" keyword can be applied to properties in ImmutableCar class to avoid compiler warning. Like this "public new string Model". Works same but explicitly shows to compiler that you really wanted to hide base class property.